# SED: Align lines LEFT instead of right on a 79-column width

Tags: text, sed, alignment, width

**SED: Align lines LEFT instead of right on a 79-column width**

I've seen the SED oneliner:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,78\}$/ &/;ta'
```

I want to do the same bij I want to align LEFT. So the question is how can I get a 79 column width with the text alingned LEFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the clarification in the comment: you can archieve that like this:

```
fold -w79 yourfile | sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{0,78\}$/& /;ta'
```

The `fold` folds long lines and the `sed` appends spaces to short lines. Note tha the `/& /` part has the space right of the `&`. This appends the space (`&` means the unmodified line).

I also changed the `{1,78}` to `{0,78}`, thus empty lines will also be expanded.

Comment: Sorry. I mean filling up the line with white spaces to accomplish that every line has the same length

Comment: Why do you also use fold? Just the sed command already did the trick with my file.

Comment: @Apojoost I used fold to shorten and fold lines longer than 79 characters.